# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation Movement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to pan a UIView.

Does `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` take delta x and delta y or the absolute value of the new position? Here's what I have:

```
- (void)swipeDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    CGPoint newTranslation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    self.navController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(newTranslation.x, 0);
    .....
}
```

This works from left to right but not from right to left. I'm pretty sure "translation" means delta x and delta y and not absolute value.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the transform is an immediate operation as it is just matrix multiplication of the view's location.

If you need to revert back from *your current position*, you can save the transform to an ivar, and use an inverse transform, ie:

`_currentTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(newTranslation.x, 0);`

and later:

`CGAffineTransform inverse = CGAffineTransformInvert(_currentTransform);`

If you want to remove all transforms you can do `self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Hope this helps!